# What should I do when I see a player using a botting service?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I just made an EUW account and found hey this ping is better than NA fancy that and well I am leveling up my account maybe 3 or 4 games a day and everyday or at least every 7 games there is one player who to me behaves like a bot. This player would first of only move every 3 or so minutes always move in one direction regardless the terrain or turrets or whatever would never buy any items till the absolute end of the game and the items would never be good for that champion. This kinda pisses me off but I do not know if its legal or not so is it and when you find a player that does what should one do?

Comment: does the "bot" in question in question try? like use skills, push the lane, participate in teamfights, etc. It's very possible they are just really bad...

Comment: No he did nothing all game. aside from what I said above

Comment: Botting is against the rules. Can't find an exact source at the moment but it is definitely not allowed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking if something is legal or not.  We are not lawyers.

Comment: Legal does not mean "legal" I could have simply been asking if it allowed or if player "can" or can not do it under the terms and conditions of use by League of legends there is nothing wrong with my question as it has nothing to do with the law you could have suggested i edit the question as it "maybe" seen as a legal question that would have been a better approach. *[Please avoid personal attacks.]*

Comment: It may help, it may not.  It's not me you need to convince, but the rest of the community.  As is, I'm the only one who's cast a close vote so far.

Comment: If someone experienced what I had and they wanted to know what I wanted to know would this question not help them? Knowledge is knowledge whether it pertains to one individual or several is irrelevant this question is directed at players in the game league of legends who may have witnessed what I had they may be interested in knowing what I was interested in knowing. I Had thought the whole purpose of stackexchange gaming was to provide knowledge

Comment: I actually think the question itself is very valid but the title is kind of confusing. The body of the question asks about how to handle players using bots and the title asks about whether or not it's against the TOS...

Comment: Valid question, period!
Anyways, I think it's a macro assigned to someone. Propably someone did the actions you described and recorded that. So now he can just do other stuff while his accounts get leveled for free (and doesn't go afk).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [League of Legends Terms of Use](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/legal/termsofuse) It clearly says under Code of Conduct (Hit CTRL-F to find it):

> J. Using any unauthorized third party programs, including but not
>   limited to "mods," "hacks," "cheats," "scripts," "bots," "trainers,"
>   and automation programs, that interact with the Software in any way,
>   for any purpose, including, without limitation, any unauthorized third
>   party programs that intercept, emulate, or redirect any communication
>   between the Software and Riot Games and any unauthorized third party
>   programs that collect information about the Game by reading areas of
>   memory used by the Software to store information;

So while I'm pretty sure It's legal (you won't go to jail for using bots) it's violiting the TOS of League and thus it can get your account banned. If you see a player botting you can report him for any reason but **add a comment to your report** so they know it's a bot and not a normal report.

I usually report those players as an unskilled player with a comment like "Might be a bot" or something like that since you can't be 100% sure whether or not they really are botting. A lot of players are also just so unimaginable bad that it looks like a bot.

Comment: I was absolutely not sure what to report the person as cause I mean I have never seen a some bot before so I had picked spamming I will send a report request cause this is really uncool for the rest of us I mean free kills for the enemy team in PVP and well not much experience for players new to the game as they may emulate these players actions and get frustrated that they keep dying and just rage quit which is what happened to me I mean I don't care I can win 1 v 5 whatever but if someone I knew had to deal with this and they trying to enjoy the game I would really hate to have to explain it

Comment: @Broken_Code Well you shouldn't be seeing bots too often. Actually I've only ever seen 3 over all and that was while leveling. One was like 4 or 5 years ago and the others were when I was leveling a smurf account. They are really rare so I think you just had some bad luck seeing 2 or 3 at once.

Comment: I think it is because the account I am leveling is only like well I created it a few days ago so its very new but I see a lot of them and most of the time its the same player well two to be precise.

Comment: I've done this, and following that I also submitted a support request about this issue. I did this after looking at the player's game history and I noticed that he/she was not buying any items in a large majority of his/her games he/she died very often in these games, not to mention the items purchased by this player were exactly the same with whether the champion was a mage, adc, support or fighter.

Comment: You shouldn't be reporting as **unskilled**.  These reports don't make it anywhere as **unskilled** isn't anything bannable.  Anything but **unskilled** could get them something.   A direct email to riot is more likely to help though.

Comment: emailing support seems like a good plan. Also I would pick "Griefing: Intentionally Feeding" or "Griefing: Assisting Enemy Team" because that's the actual impact on the game. Of course add the comment "This account is most probably (using) a bot.".

Comment: Yeah I honestly do not think riot even looks at the unskilled reports. So I Simply send a support request. No offense to all EUW players But there are an awful lot of botting players here I think today I saw my 3rd in the past 3 days and this is on my level 30 account. His match history is more or less exactly like the other players 10+ deaths one or two assists that random kill and like 2 items (warmorgs bots and pots being just one of the few he would use). I guess it maybe because well I just recently transferred my NA account here

Comment: Riot does not look at "unskilled" reports. According to the docs somewhere, it just reduces their MMR for non-ranked matches.